# What is the minimum interval between retries to an unresponsive NTP server?

Tags: ntpd

`ntpd` is the reference implementation of NTP.  The current version is 4.1.2.

The manual page *seems* to say that when `iburst` is used, the interval between retries to an unresponsive NTP server is 16 seconds.

http://doc.ntp.org/4.1.2/confopt.htm

> `iburst`
>
> When the server is unreachable and at each poll interval, send a burst of eight packets instead of the usual one. As long as the server is unreachable, the spacing between packets is about 16s to allow a modem call to complete. Once the server is reachable, the spacing between packets is about 2s. This is designed to speed the initial synchronization acquisition with the server command and s addresses and when ntpd is started with the `-q` option.

But the official NTP "handbook" says the retry interval will be raised to 64 seconds (assuming default settings):

https://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/poll.html

> For the `iburst` option the number of packets in the burst is six, which
>   is the number normally needed to synchronize the clock; for the `burst`
>   option, the number of packets in the burst is determined by the
>   difference between the current poll exponent and the minimum poll
>   exponent as a power of 2. For instance, with **the default minimum poll
>   exponent of 6 (64 s)**, only one packet is sent for every poll, while
>   the full number of eight packets is sent at poll exponents of 9 (512
>   s) or more. This insures that the average headway will never exceed
>   the minimum headway.
>
> The burst options can result in increased load on the network if not
>   carefully designed. Both options are affected by the provisions
>   described on the Rate Management and the Kiss-o'-Death Packet page. **In
>   addition, when `iburst` or `burst` are enabled, the first packet of the
>   burst is sent, but the remaining packets sent only when the reply to
>   the first packet is received. If no reply has been received after a
>   timeout set by the `minpoll` option, the first packet is sent again.
>   This means that, even if a server is unreachable, the network load is
>   no more than at the minimum poll interval.**

Should I understand the interval between retries will actually be 64 seconds when using `iburst`, unless the `minpoll` option is also adjusted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `iburst` setting alters the `server` setting so that until the server is reachable, *at each poll interval* eight packets are sent instead of one. (The interval between each of the eight packets is either 16 seconds or 2 seconds, depending on whether or not any response is received.)

To try and answer your question specifically, the interval between polling retries will be at least 64 seconds whether or not `iburst` is used.

- When `iburst` is not used, one packet will be sent per server polling retry.
- When `iburst` is used, up to eight packets will be sent at either 16 second or 2 second intervals for each polling retry.
- Once the server is considered reachable (and therefore a candidate for synchronisation), the `iburst` flag has no futher effect.
- To use the `iburst` semantics once a server is a candidate for synchronisation, add the `burst` flag.
- It is permitted (but not necessarily recommended) to use `iburst` and `burst` for the same server.

---

After some experimentation, here is what actually happens for me:

- When `iburst` is specified and the server does not reply, one packet is sent every polling interval.
- When `iburst` is specified and the server does reply, an initial sequence of six packets are sent, one every two seconds. This is not repeated at subsequent polling intervals, and `iburst` has no further effect. This sequence of six packets is sufficient to mark the server as a potential candidate for synchronisation (`*` in the left-hand column of `ntpq -np`).
- Once `iburst` has no further effect, a single packet is sent every polling interval.
- Each successful polling interval increments the reachability by 1 (actually consider it a bitwise shift register with 1 being pushed in as the LSB); once it reaches 777 - in octal - corresponding to nine consecutive successful poll intervals, the server becomes a possible synchronisation source.

Very little of this matches the current documentation!

Comment: hmm.  or there is a subtlety in your answer that i do not understand.  Does ntpd make a distinction between a server that is not yet reachable, v.s. a server that it has not received any responses from?

Comment: @sourcejedi I believe there is a difference, yes, but I'm hoping to be able to check it out either later tonight or tomorrow at some point during the day. I'm working on the basis that reachable = "is a candidate for synchronisation".

Comment: @sourcejedi interesting discoveries. Hope it's useful

Comment: *Much* of that is what I thought the handbook meant. The "becomes a possible syncronization source" sounds relevant to the question I had in mind. Very roughly, it sounds like the server has to be reachable for 9 successive tests at 64 second intervals before you can start. E.g. if the client is only ever turned on for 5 minutes at a time, it would never make any progress towards syncing at all. I don't see that reflected in https://tools.ietf.org/rfcmarkup/5905. I only see that a server is considered "unreachable" if none of the last 8 (9? i hate fenceposts) poll intervals received a reply.